# Problems with extracting params in nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Hi guys I'm having challenges with extracting params from my route in nuxt 3.

The structure of my dynamic route looks like this exam_[id]_[applicant_id].vue and after loading my route looks like this http://localhost:3000/e-recruitment/exam_cl96q0u040000v1ocg2ffryio_3 and my to dynamic params are cl96q0u040000v1ocg2ffryio and 3, when I console log the params object I get this object [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mSXV.png), what might be the problem

```js
onMounted(async ()=>{
            console.log(route.params.applicant_id)
            console.log(route.params.id)
            })
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for onMounted hook or async function here. You need to call the [useRoute](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-route/) composable.

```html
<script setup>    
const route = useRoute();
console.log(route.params.applicant_id)
console.log(route.params.id)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies within the underscores (`_`) used in your pages route name.

If you rename your page to `exam-[id]-[applicant_id].vue`, the route params, when accessing `/exam-cl96q0u040000v1ocg2ffryio-3` look like this:

```js
{id: 'cl96q0u040000v1ocg2ffryio', applicant_id: '3'}
```